# Assigning classes after page reload based on variable value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla3.0

I am currently developing a new Joomla based website. During the creation process I stumbled upon a problem causing me headaches:

I need to en- or disable three modules based on the user clicking one of three links. In theory, everything seems easy: creating three links with unique IDs, creating a short snippet of javascript code and finally saving saving the variable value to the local storage so the chosen option will be visible after page reload.

This is what I created so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="wahl">
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
<li><a id="no1" href="#">Option 1</a></li>
<li><a id="no2" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
<li><a id="no3" href="#">Option 3</a></li>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clickedclass = 0
clickedclass = localStorage.getItem(classvar)

jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    jQuery('#no1').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem(classvar, 1);
    });
});

if (clickedclass == 0)
{ document.write ("Variable is 0") }
else if (clickedclass == 1)
{
jQuery('#no1').addClass('active');
document.write ("Variable is 1")
}
else if (clickedclass == 2)
{ document.write ("Variable is 2") }
else if (clickedclass == 3)
{ document.write ("Variable is 3") }
</script>
```

The if / else if statement itself works, I tested this before. Changing the value of the variable does not work, saving the change to local storage does not, either. All in all it seems all jQuery statements do not work. I am using "jQuery" instead of the dollar sign because Joomla won't recognize jQuery commands with the dollar sign. What is the mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can't change the variable and on page reload to expect that the variable will be the new value except if you use cookies or local storage and I can't see anything like that in your code :)

Comment: `var clickedclass=1` inside click handler creates a different variable than the first one you declare. Read up on scope and closures in javascript

Comment: BojanPetkovski: I added the localStorage part now, it should work actually - if the jQuery part was running, actually.

charlietfl: thx, totally missed that one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl has the right idea: you're redefining a new `clickedclass` variable inside of your click handler, so what you're modifying is this new variable instead of the more global one. Removing the `var` from your statement will cause javascript to look for variables with the same name in higher scopes, which is what you want here.

As for your dollar sign "problem", Joomla most certainly behaves that way to avoid libraries collisions. Many libraries use this `$` as an entry point, each one redefining it, so having several of them would make them break each other. For that reason, JQuery gives you another entry point which is the `JQuery` object. If you want to use the `$` anyway, then you can (and you most often should) limit your code's scope with this bit of code:

```
(function($) {
    //your code here using $
})(jQuery);
```

**EDIT:**
After your edit, your `classvar` variable is undefined, so that can't work, after defining it to w/e, your code seems to be working for me.

Comment: Thanks a million. After defining the variable, everything works as it should - finally.

Thanks also to everyone else. You guys are just simply awesome!

Comment: No problem, in the future, remember to check your development tools console for errors. Your browser should have noticed you that the variable was undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try if changing the value of the variable with the jQuery.click() works when you wrap the click event into a `jQuery(document).ready()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
    jQuery('#no1').click(function() {
      clickedclass = 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: get rid of the `var` or it's a completely different variable (contained in a closure) with same name

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I immediately tried this out. However, the jQuery part does not seem to work. Thanks anyway!